# How can define an indicator which measures the degree of similarity between two signals?

Tags: autocorrelation, cross-correlation, dsp-core

The similarity of two signals is calculated by cross correlation. But, how to define an indicator which quantitatively measures the degree of similarity between two signals? Thanks.

Comment: normalize your cross correlation, Stephan.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that you need that is not provided by correlation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming finite power signals:

$$ \lVert x \rVert^2 \triangleq \lim_{N \to \infty} \ \frac{1}{2N+1} \sum\limits_{n=-N}^{+N} \big|x[n] \big|^2 \ < +\infty $$

this is a Hilbert Space sorta thingie.

define inner product:

$$ \langle x,y \rangle \triangleq \lim_{N \to \infty} \ \frac{1}{2N+1} \sum\limits_{n=-N}^{+N} x[n] \cdot \overline{y}[n] $$

where $\overline{y}[n] $ is the complex conjugate of $y[n]$.
so this is true about the norm:

$$ \lVert x \rVert = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle} $$

Cross-Correlation:

$$ R_{xy}[k] \triangleq \langle x[n], y[n+k] \rangle $$

Autoorrelation:

$$ R_{xx}[k] \triangleq \langle x[n], x[n+k] \rangle \ \le R_{xx}[0] = \lVert x \rVert^2 $$

Normalized Autocorrelation (sometimes called "autocovariance")

$$ -1 \le \frac{R_{xx}[k]}{R_{xx}[0]} \triangleq \frac{\langle x[n], x[n+k] \rangle}{\langle x[n], x[n] \rangle} \ \le  1 $$

Normalized Crosscorrelation:

$$ -1 \le \frac{R_{xy}[k]}{\lVert x \rVert \lVert y \rVert} \triangleq \frac{\langle x[n], y[n+k] \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle x[n], x[n] \rangle}\sqrt{\langle y[n], y[n] \rangle}} \ \le  1 $$

Comment: Dear @robertbristow-johnson, thanks for your nice solution.

Comment: just a mistake. Excuse me.

Answer (score 5):

The general topic of finding similarities between signals is wide ranging:

- are the signals of same sampling, length, offset, shift or scale?
- where do they take their values (discrete, real, complex)?
- are they stationary? noisy?
- what do you consider similar (whole signals, chunks, specific features)?
- which are the invariances looked for?
- and most important: what is your goal?

The following works provide an overview of some common similarity metrics, which one can normalize into an index:

- [Clustering of time series data --- a survey](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.patcog.2005.01.025), section 2.2. Similarity/distance measures
- [Similarity Measures and Dimensionality Reduction Techniques for Time Series Data Mining](http://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs/39030/InTech-Similarity_measures_and_dimensionality_reduction_techniques_for_time_series_data_mining.pdf), section 3. Similarity measures

Comment: This is called a useful answer.

Comment: Dear @Laurent Duval, thanks for your nice answer.

Answer (score 4):

if you are searching for similarity between two signals in frequency domain, you can go for coherence. Coherence indicates frequency components common to both signals